# Variable sized keyword arguments in Julia

Tags: arguments, metaprogramming, julia, keyword-argument, type-stability

I'm writing a convex solver, for concreteness' sake assume it's solving ordinary least squares: find x that minimizes ||b-Ax||^2.  So my function call would look like

```
x = optim(A, b)
```

I would like to be able to use warm-starts when they are useful, to provide a good initial guess at the solution.  So something like

```
x = optim(A, b; w=some_starting_value)
```

My problem is that if I want to use a default value, `some_starting_value` needs to be of length equal to the number of columns in `A`, which is chosen by the user.  In R it's possible to do something like

```
x = optim(A, b; w=ncols(A))
```

Does any similar functionality exist in Julia?  My current solution is to do something like

x = optim(A, b; w=0)

and then check if `w != 0` and set it to be the right size vector inside the `optim` function.  But that seems hacky and (I assume) messes with type stability.

Is there a clean way to specify a keyword argument whose size depends on a required argument?

**Edit**
It looks like something like

```
function foo{T<:Real}(A::Array{T,2}; w=zeros(T,size(x,2)))
    println("$x")
    println("$y")
end
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that default parameters in Julia can be expressions containing the values of the other parameters:

```
julia> a(x, y=2*x) = println("$x, $y")
a (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> a(10)
10, 20
```

Additionally the default parameter expressions can make calls to other functions:

```
julia> b(x) = sqrt(x)
b (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a(x, y=b(x)) = println("$x, $y")
a (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> a(100)
100, 10.0
```